# Set enum property of class dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using .net core 3.1 and I have a method `FillData`. **I want to set randomly (or it can be enum's first value) enum values to my object** but I can't achieve this. How can I write commented line in below?  Below code is runnable for reproducing by directly copy pasting to https://dotnetfiddle.net/

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var wantedObject = MyHelper.FillData<Student>();
        Console.WriteLine(wantedObject.Gender);
    }

    public static class MyHelper
    {
        public static T FillData<T>()
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
            var resultObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[]{});
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    property.SetValue(resultObject, "asdf");
                }
                else if (property.PropertyType.BaseType.FullName == "System.Enum")
                {
                    // property.SetValue(resultObject, ???????? );
                }
            }

            return resultObject;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public string Surname{get;set;}
        public GenderEnum Gender{get;set;}
        public LevelEnum Level{get;set;}
    }

    public enum GenderEnum
    {
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2,
    }

    public enum LevelEnum
    {
        High = 1,
        Low = 2,
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the available values `Enum.GetValues(..)` then select one at random

Comment: As an aside, suffixing the names of enums with `Enum` is [recommended against](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces#names-of-common-types), and is something the framework classes consistently avoid. `public Level Level { get; set; }` is unambiguous.

Comment: Yes you're right, naming convention said like you @JeroenMostert .But, in big project, when I didn't wrote enum, everything mixing like `entities, DTOs, enums, models`. So, I write enum for distinguish from other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the available values `Enum.GetValues(Type)`, then select one at random

For example

```
//...

Array values = Enum.GetValues(property.PropertyType);
int index = random.Next(0, values.Length - 1); //Assuming a Random class
object value = values.GetValue(index);

property.SetValue(resultObject, value);

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to default to the default value then you can use the [DefaultValue] attribute.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var wantedObject = MyHelper.FillData<Student>();
        Console.WriteLine(wantedObject.Gender);
    }

    public static class MyHelper
    {
        public static T FillData<T>()
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
            var resultObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[]{});
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    property.SetValue(resultObject, "asdf");
                }
                else if (property.PropertyType.BaseType.FullName == "System.Enum")
                {
                   DefaultValueAttribute[] attributes = property.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), false) as DefaultValueAttribute[];
                   if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                        property.SetValue(resultObject, attributes[0].Value);
                    else
                    //..do something here to get a random value.
                        property.SetValue(resultObject, 0);
                }
            }

            return resultObject;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public string Surname{get;set;}
        public GenderEnum Gender{get;set;}
        public LevelEnum Level{get;set;}
    }

    [DefaultValue(Male)]
    public enum GenderEnum
    {
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2,
    }

    [DefaultValue(High)]
    public enum LevelEnum
    {
        High = 1,
        Low = 2,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RushBush . Your solution also solve my problem. But, It's difficult writing DefaultValue to hundreds of enums. I'm sure your solution will help other people, but Nkosi's answer is more appropriate to me.